# Robotframework: How to use a value form one list as a part of the name of another list

Tags: list, python-2.7, variables, robotframework

I am trying to create a list whose name should include one of the values from another list. To simplify, I have created a following simple example.

Create first list

```
@{list.1}   create list  1  2   3
log  ${list.1}[1]
```

Get the second value from the list

```
${list1_2ndValue} =    get from list   ${list.1}    1
log     ${list1_2ndvalue}
```

Use this value in a new list as part of its name. New list name should be @{list.2}

```
@{list.${list1_2ndValue}}   create list  a  b  c
```

It fails with *No keyword with name '@{list.${list1_2ndValue}}' found.* error

Tried different methods but no luck. How can I use another list value in the name of new list. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this seems like it would make your code really hard to understand. Why do you need to compute the name of a variable? What problem does that solve?

Comment: You are right, it will make code hard to understand. I am doing data verification. We have a list that has all the document ids. There is an excel sheet with all the information to be verified for all those documents. There is already a code that extracts information from excel. I am trying to loop each doc id in the list, extract related info from excel and store in a list whose name should also include the document id (needed for further verification). If there is no solution to this problem, we may have to redo the code that extracts data from excel.

Comment: It sounds like a dictionary would be easier to use than a bunch of dynamic variables. Just create an empty dictionary, and then use the document id to be the key in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. That's another option.